# C# - Get all System.Windows.Media.Fonts

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, system.drawing, system.windows.media

How to get all fonts from System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.FamilyNames ?

I know code samples are there for [System.Drawing.Fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font?view=netframework-3.5) but not for [System.Windows.Media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily.familynames?view=netframework-3.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go with [System.Drawing.Fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font?view=netframework-3.5) at the end..